# Prong covers for AC power cords

Tags: power-supply, accessories, hardware-selection

Apologies if this question is somewhat off-topic (it seems marginally-related to computer hardware based on the FAQ, but I didn't see a more appropriate Stack Exchange forum).

I'm looking for plastic covers that slip onto 2-prong AC power cords and adapters, so that the metal prongs don't poke holes into carrying bags or whatnot during transport. I know that such things exist, since one was included with the AC adapter of my DSL modem (thus I have one -- but I want a few more). However, I can't figure out what terms to use to search for such an item. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the following company which sells them as "2-Prong NEMA 1-15P Power Connector Cap/Cover": http://www.vpi.us/power-covers.html#

Answer (score 2):

Use a short piece of tubing (e.g., shrink tubing) with the ends slipped over the prongs.

Comment: Here I was looking through esoteric parts-suppliers.  This seems creative.  A ball of Play-Doh seems possibly as well.